# Определить множество, на котором данное отношение является функциональным, биективным

Tags: дискретная-математика

Определить множество (если это возможно), на которой данное
отношение являются: а) функциональным; б) биективним:
Как это решить
Может кто-то скинет пример решения подобной задачи

[image: 1]

[image: график функции]

Comment: `а) (ℝ×ℝ₊) б) (ℝ₊×ℝ₊)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращаем внимание, что при x<0, y не определён (я бы поспорил, но пусть так)
Также на x⊆ℝ₊ функция монотонно возрастает

- ℝ — множество действительных чисел
- ∪ℝ₊ — множество неотрицательных действительных чисел

> ```
> а) ℝ×∪ℝ₊
> ```

Функциональное отношение — это когда для каждого элемента первого множества есть не более одного элемента второго.

То есть, если x⊆ℝ, то для каждого будет либо 0, либо 1 значение в множестве y⊆∪ℝ₊

---

> ```
> б) ∪ℝ₊×∪ℝ₊
> ```

Биективное отношение(отображение) — это такое, в котором, для каждого элемента первого множества есть ровно один элемент второго и наоборот.

То есть, если x⊆∪ℝ₊, то для каждого будет ровно 1 значение в множестве y⊆∪ℝ₊ и наоборот, каждому такому y соответствует ровно 1 значение x.

Comment: А что означает плюс около R,
Зростает?

Comment: Положительные означает. С нулём - неотрицательные получаются. В ответе есть по этому поводу пояснение.